# Unable to find/import Runwith Class in org.junit.runner?

Tags: java, class, selenium, import, junit

The below error appears, when I import Runwith, in org.junit.runner...

***The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Runwith***

It gave me the suggestion for creating a class in the Junit-Runner package...I don't know, what should I put in that code...

Junit-4.10 is there in libraries and Build Path. I am using it and am not sure whether it is an issue with Junit or Selenium...Any suggestions pls..??

This is the code, I am using and getting the error where the @Runwith is used.(Line #2 and #5)

```
package package1;
import org.junit.runner.Runwith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@Runwith(Suite.Class)
@SuiteClasses({WPHomePage.class, WPRegisterpage.class})

public class BatchJavaFile {

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@Runwith(Suite.Class)` should be `@RunWith(Suite.class)` (note capitalization)

You probably also need another import

```
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
```